# Unable to pass List<string> from method 1 to method 2

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am working with Microsoft Azure's library. I am trying to dynamically return a list of containers, where I can pass into Microsoft Azure's code as a argument. Both methods are within the same class.

**ListContainer()**

```
 static public List<string> ListContainer(StartConfig config)
 {
    List<string> container = new List<string>();

    if (config == null || config.BlobClient == null)
    {
        config = Program.GetConfig();
    }

        //Get the list of the blob from the above container
    IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = config.BlobClient.ListContainers();

    foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
    {
       container.Add(item.Name);
    }

    //Adding a print statement
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", container));
    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    return container;
}
```

**GetConfig()**

```
public static StartConfig GetConfig()
{
    StartConfig config = new StartConfig();

    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
   config.StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Create the blob object.
    config.BlobClient = config.StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();


    //Get a reference to a container to use for the sample code, and create it if it does not exist.
    config.Container = config.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(//List of Container names which are returned from ListContainer());

    //Create the container if it does not exisit.
    config.Container.CreateIfNotExists();

    return config;
}
```

I tired to simply call the method `ListContainer()` as `var test = ListContiner(null)` and placing that within my `GetConfig()`. When I did that I would get an [StackOverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx). It is because the `ListContainer` is checking to make sure `config` is not null and then running `GetConfig()` and assigning it to config. If anyone has any ideas on how to simply populate `config.Container = config.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER_NAME);` in `GetConfig()` with the list of containers from `ListContainers()` that would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `var test = ListContainer(null)` inside `GetConfig` method, whenever you call `GetConfig`, it will call `ListContainer(null)`, which checks if `config == null` and calls `GetConfig` again, throwning the `StackOverflowException`.

You have to break the cycle somehow.
My suggestion is instead of calling `GetConfig` inside `ListContainer`, you require a `config` to be passed to it and put a guard to protect yourself if the caller doesn't.

```
public static List<string> ListContainer(StartConfig config)
{
    if (config == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
    if (config.BlobClient == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("BlobClient must not be null", "config");

    List<string> container = new List<string>();

    //Get the list of the blob from the above container
    IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = config.BlobClient.ListContainers();

    foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
    {
       container.Add(item.Name);
    }

    //Adding a print statement
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", container));
    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    return container;
}
```

You would also change the `GetConfig` method to call the `ListContainer` passing the `config`:

```
public static StartConfig GetConfig()
{
    StartConfig config = new StartConfig();

    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    config.StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Create the blob object.
    config.BlobClient = config.StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    var containers = ListContainer(config);

    //Get a reference to a container to use for the sample code, and create it if it does not exist.
    config.Container = config.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(//List of Container names which are returned from ListContainer());

    //Create the container if it does not exisit.
    config.Container.CreateIfNotExists();

    return config;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of a code sample of how I would go about doing the "you require a config to be passed to it and a guard to protect yourself" ?

Comment: I already did. The two ifs at the beginning of the method will guard your method against a null config and config.BlobClient.